# How does predicate work in this situation?

Tags: java, predicate

I am trying to understand how predicate works in this situation. It looks simple but I don't understand what it does when combines with other classes and methods.

This is something new to me. I tried to debug I but got nothing.

```
Predicate<String> delete = (strings) ->{
    return !strings.startsWith(sNextNode.nameOfString))|| !Note_Tree.PATTERN.matcher(strings).find();
};
List<String> arrayChild = nodeRoot.childNameList();
arrayChild.removeIf(delete);

PATTERNS is just Pattern.compile("[0-9]");
```

I don't want the other nodes to be deleted if they are not the same. I want to keep them. This takes the same node names but not the other if not similar.

Or perhaps if you can provide an example on how to use predicate with almost the same situation if you can. Pls. Much appreciated.

Comment: The return part. I don't understand how it works. I have looked similar questions but they showed nothing similar as this. No return parts.

Comment: Yes. This makes sense.

Comment: Hmm. I think I can use this sense to punch something in my code. Hopefully it works.

Comment: question... What is the difference between.!strings.startsWith(sNextNode.nameOfString))|| !Note_Tree.PATTERN.matcher(strings).find(); and strings.startsWith(sNextNode.nameOfString))|| Note_Tree.PATTERN.matcher(strings).find(); The exclamation mark on both with and without it.

Comment: Yeah. This is bad. No luck.